# Filling holes in 3D volume

Tags: python, image-processing, simpleitk, mathematical-morphology

I am trying to find libraries that can fill **small cavity** inside a volume as well as a **hole that is through the volume** like a tube. I had tried **SimpleITK** but didn't got any success with that. I had tried all the *GrayScale Morphological* operation there but these holes are not getting filled up.
I would like to know the solution for this problem.

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
image = sitk.ReadImage("volume.mha")
filt_1 = sitk.GrayscaleFillholeImageFilter()
filt_2 = sitk.GrayscaleMorphologicalClosingImageFilter()
output_1 = filt_1.Execute(image)
output_2 = filt_2.Execute(image)
```

The filters are being created in such a manner with default parameters and are applied then on the input image.

Comment: What you need to solve this most likely is [morphological closing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)). However, in order for the community to help you, please post a [minimal, reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I had tried morphological closing with filters of SimpleITK using Python.  I had also tried Fill Hole filter also but it didn't work/ The code was nothing just creating instance of filter using Python and SimpleITK. But nothing worked.

Comment: Again, without posting your Code, no one will be able to help you with this.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code i had used. I had used Morphological closing with default parameters. Kernel Radius being set to default i.e. (1,1,1) . Increasing this fills the spaces that are neither holes nor tubes through the volume.

Comment: Good, that's a start. Now it would be helpful if you could either make the data in question accessible or describe it's properties better. Is the data grayscale or rgb? Which type is it, uint8/24 or float? How big are the holes in the data? How did you assess that the closing operation did not work? Can you post slices of your 3D data rendered as images before and after the closing operation? Have you played around with kernel sizes?

Comment: The data is grayscale data of 64 bit float. After applying the Closing operation, I visualized the data using 3D slicer, but the holes were there and not filled. I had kept the kernel size to (1,1,1), increasing the kernel size merges the two different sections of the image. It basically fills up the space which are not holes.

Comment: Are you sure the sitk methods you used work for float64? Also, are you sure the methods work on 3D data? Regardless of that, performing a morphological closing with a kernel size of (1,1,1) will either do nothing, or close holes of size (1,1,1), depending on the implementation. Is there any particular reason you want to use this obscure sitk package? I have never seen a worse documentation. If there is no particular reason, I would strongly suggest to use a more common and better documented package, you could have a look at `scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_closing`

Comment: I am completely flexible considering the usage of libraries. It had tried scipy as well. It hadn't worked with kernel size (1,1,1). Can you suggest something else. Till the time let me play around the parameters for this closing function from scipy.

Comment: After playing around with the parameters, some of the holes having value 0 are getting filled with half the value of nearest value. Let's say hole is having value 0 and nearest value is 18 so some of the holes are getting value (0 + 18) / 2 = 9. But i want that hole to have value 18 so i had changed the mode to nearest as written in [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_closing.html). But it didn't worked. I am getting same kind of behaviour with Scipy and SimpleITK packages.

Comment: Have you read up on how a morphological closing operation is working? You have to choose your kernel size in the same range as the largest holes you want to fill. What is your largest whole size? Regarding you nearest neighbor observation: Have you considered the neighboring voxels in all 3 dimensions? Or did you just look at the neighbors in slices along one plane?

Comment: On your query regarding the kernel size, I know kernel size should be set to the largest hole size but setting it to larger size, fills up the regions that are neither holes nor tubes. I had visualized that in all 3 dimensions. The observation that i gave was considering all the 3 dimension rather than just considering slices through the plane.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, however, this answer could be use for the ones dealing with the same problem:

```py
import SimpleITK as sitk

image = sitk.ReadImage("volume.mha")
#be sure that you have a binary or grayscale image
binary_image = sitk.BinaryThreshold(image, 0.5, 1, 1, 0)
dims = segmentation.GetDimension()
# then apply a fillhole algorithm
filledMask = sitk.BinaryFillhole(segmentation)
# since the method before perfoms a dilation, try a erosion afterwards
erodedMask  = sitk.BinaryErode(filledMask, [3]*dims)
```